# Why does getline not result in the text I expected?

Tags: c++, getline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help with getline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744665/need-help-with-getline)

In the  following code, my getline is skipped entirely and doesn't prompt for input.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int UserTicket[8];
    int WinningNums[8];
    char options;
    string userName;

    cout << "LITTLETON CITY LOTTO MODEL: " << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "1) Play Lotto " << endl;
    cout << "q) Quit Program " << endl;
    cout << "Please make a selection: " << endl;

    cin >> options;

    switch (options)
    {
    case 'q':
        return 0;
        break;

    case '1':
        {
            cout << "Please enter your name please: " << endl;
            getline(cin, userName);
            cout << userName;
        }
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Under what conditions? Runtime error? Compiler error? What are you trying to do? Can you crystallize it to a smaller example?

Comment: Nice way to make people start thinking...

Comment: also, is this homework? If so it should be labeled as such.

Comment: like itll just skip the getline statement completely

Comment: This is getting to be a FAQ. I think this is the third or fourth time I've seen this question in the last few days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
cin >> options;
```

You can only extract (`>>`) from `cin` when the user hits enter. So the user types <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> and that line executes. Since `options` is a `char`, it extracts a single character (`1`) from `cin` and stores it in `options`. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> is still in the stdin buffer, since nothing has consumed it yet. When you get to the `getline` call, the first thing it sees in the buffer is the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which marks the end of input, so `getline` immediately returns an empty string.

There's lots of ways to fix it; probably the easiest way that fits with the model you're using in your program is to tell `cin` to ignore the next character in its buffer:

```
cin >> options;
cin.ignore();
```

Comment: thanks i forgot to put the cin.ignore();

Comment: +1 for cool buttons. I'd never seen that before.