# getline() does not work if used after some inputs

Tags: c++, char, getline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help with getline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744665/need-help-with-getline)

`getline()` is not working, if I use it after some inputs, i.e.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
string date,time;
char journal[23];


cout<<"Date:\t";
cin>>date;
cout<<"Time:\t";
cin>>time;

cout<<"Journal Entry:\t";
cin.getline(journal,23);


cout<<endl;
system("pause");
}
```

where as if I use `getline()` on top of inputs, it does work i.e.

```
cout<<"Journal Entry:\t";
cin.getline(journal,23);
cout<<"Date:\t";
cin>>date;
cout<<"Time:\t";
cin>>time;
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: Please define "is not working". What results did you expect, and what did you get?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

> Characters are extracted until either (n - 1) characters have been
> extracted or the delimiting character is found (which is delimiter if this
> parameter is specified, or '\n' otherwise). The extraction also stops
> if the end of the file is reached in the input sequence or if an error
> occurs during the input operation.

When `cin.getline()` reads from the input, there is a newline character left in the input stream, so it doesn't read your c-string. Use `cin.ignore()` before calling `getline()`.

```
cout<<"Journal Entry:\t";
cin.ignore();
cin.getline(journal,23);
```

Comment: what's about `int` still `\n` caused the problem for `getline()`?

Comment: This is so important thing and is not mentioned in many of the websites explaining the functionality of getline.

Answer (score 14):

Adding to what @DavidHammen said:

The extraction operations leave the trailing `'\n'` character in the stream. On the other hand, `istream::getline()` discards it. So when you call `getline` after an extraction operator, `'\n'` is the first character it encounters and it stops reading right there.

Put this after before `getline` call extraction:

`cin.ignore()`

A more robust way of taking input would be something like this:

```
while (true) {

    cout<<"Time:\t";
    if (cin>>time) {
        cin.ignore();  // discard the trailing '\n'
        break;
    } else {
        // ignore everything or to the first '\n', whichever comes first
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin.clear();  // clear the error flags
        cout << "Invalid input, try again.\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not checking stream status. The `std::cin` stream extraction operator (`operator>>`) can fail. When it does, the stream is marked as "bad" (`failbit`, `badbit`, or `eofbit` are set). Once "bad", all subsequent stream extractions on that stream will fail unless you clear the status.

Learn to be a paranoid programmer. Always check status of those formatted input operations. You could, for example throw an exception, or print an error message and exit. The one thing you shouldn't do is to simply assume that it worked.