# cin.getline() function not working properly after cin?

Tags: c++, string, cin

I am trying the following code:

```
int main() 
{
    char str1[20];
    int a;
    cout << "Enter Integer:"
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Integer:"<<a<<endl;
    cout << "Enter string:"<<endl;
    cin.getline(str1,20);
    cout << "Input String is:"<<str1;
    return 0;
}
```

and OUTPUT is:

```
Enter Integer:20
Integer:20
Enter string:
Input String is:
```

I am able to enter the string when not accepting integer using cin, but when I try to use cin.getline() after cin, its not working.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744665/need-help-with-getline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `operator>>` ignores whitespace (i.e. `' ', '\t', '\n'`) **before** a field, i.e. it reads until **before** the next whitespace.

`getline` on the other hand reads **until and including** the next line break, and returns the text **before** the linebreak.

Consequently, if you do first `operator>>` before a line-break and then `getline`, the `operator>>` will read until before the line-break, and getline will read only until after the line-break, returning an empty string.

Note: what you have in the input buffer after entering "20, 20, mystring" is effectively

```
20\n20\nmystring
```

Hence

- the first `operator>>` reads and returns `20`
- the second `operator>>` reads until after the second `20`, swallows the first `\n` and returns the second `20`
- `getline` reads until the second `\n` and returns the text before that, i.e. nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the function **gets()**, i prefer it for accepting strings and the only parameter that you need to pass is the string name.