# function isn't returning the desired string

Tags: c++, string, function, loops

I'm trying to make a function that filters out all the punctuation and spaces in a sentences and returns only the letters and numbers in a new string.

ex. If I type: Hi, my name is Zach1234.
    I want it to return only: himynameiszach1234

Yet it it keeps returning only the first letter.
Any ideas on how to remedy this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

string filter(string str)
{
    string result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < (str.size()-1); i++)
    {
        if(isspace(str[i]))continue;
        if(ispunct(str[i]))continue;
        if(isdigit(str[i]))result += str[i];
        if(isalpha(str[i]))result += str[i];
    }
    return(result);
}


int main()
{
    string happy;

    cout <<"Please enter a string\n";
    cin >> happy;

    cout << filter(happy) << endl;

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: First off you should be using `getline()` to read in input with spaces.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's exactly the issue, you should post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `cin >> happy;` is not reading in all of your input.  The `>>` operator will stop at the first white space character it reads and leave that in the stream.  Instead you need to use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

```
std::getline(std::cin, happy)
```

This will store the contents from the stream into `happy` until it reaches a newline or the end of file.  If it does read in a newline then it is not added to the string but it is discarded.  You do need to take care when mixing `>>` and `getline() though: [Need help with getline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744665/need-help-with-getline)

As mentioned by [user5141375](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5141375/user5141375) your for loop is also incorect.  `size()` returns the number of characters in the string so you need to loop to `i < str.size()` and not `i < str.size() - 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> happy;
```

This code read a string from your input until get a space, so if you type:

> Hi, my name is Zach1234

You will get:

> Hi;

For this loop,

```
for(int i = 0; i < (str.size()-1); i++)
```

the condition should be: `i < str.size()` or `i <= str.size() - 1`

Comment: Please use `i < str.size()` - it's more idiomatic than `i <= str.size() - 1`. A `<=` in a for loop test is something that always requires extra examination.  For example, in this case it will cause a problem when `str.size()` happens to be 0.

Comment: Hey, as you can see, I edited your answer to make it a lot more readable. In the future, you should take full advantage of SO's formatting features to make better and more readable answers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I should have been using getline() instead of cin.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use isalnum() for your filter function to consolidate.