# C++ : Getline Function Mechanics

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
   int num;
   cin >> num;
   string s;
   getline(cin, s);
   cout << s << " " << num << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

In this code if I input 3 and press enter, then s takes an empty string.

1) If it is taking the first character as a newline, then is there a possible solution of taking line as input after taking an integer as input?

2) If my input is 4567artyu then how it is deciding whether 7 has to go into the s or num ?

Comment: Not clear what your first question is. If the first character happens to be the newline, your ine is empty. If it does not, it is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help with getline()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744665/need-help-with-getline)

Comment: for example if i want 24 in num and "45tyu" in s..then how should i do it?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you always read complete lines of input from your users.  It will cause the least confusion.

- Ask for input.
- Use `std::getline` to read a line of input.
- If you don't want a string but, say, an integer, use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or (more general) [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) to safely convert the input to your desired target type.  This is where you catch poor inputs and complain at the user.

I don't think that many users, if prompted for a number, would expect that entering `42bananas` would be accepted as 42 and the `bananas` part be “remembered” for later.  It will most likely be a typo and the user will be happy to be asked to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

For taking line as input after taking integer as input you can consider removing the stray '\n' character from the stream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int num;
   cin >> num;
   getchar();
   string s;
   getline(cin, s);
   cout << s << " " << num << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This will do the trick.

For second question, it reads `4567` as integer, it will continue to read it as integer until limit of int is reached and if limit is reached it will not consider anything after that. Then it will put the maximum value of int in the variable `num` and `null` int the string `s`. If limit is not reached, then string will remain in the input stream as it is, and will be fetched by variable `s`.

Answer (score -2):

Try using cin.clear before you accept string

Comment: `clear()` clears the error flags on the stream.  It does not clear out any input in the stream.