# getline(cin, str) not working

Tags: c++, getline

My program prompts the user for a file name and I use getline to put it into my string variable. getline is not storing the user's input into filename. Why?

```
int main() {
string fileName;
cout << "==============================================================\n"
<< "|        Welcome to the Automatic Maze Path Finder!      |\n"
<< "=============================================================\n"
<< "\nEnter the name of the Maze configuration file: ";
getline(cin, fileName);
```

Also when using cout statements to test it puts the output onto the current command line. 
Ex:
user@computer:~$ //program output goes here for some reason?
Why is it doing this??

Comment: Where do you want the console output to go?

Comment: How do you know it's not storing it into `filename`? Have you run through it with a debugger?

Comment: Could you be running into this problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744665/need-help-with-getline

Comment: If I use a cout statement for fileName after getline, the program does not display anything

Comment: The program completely stops after the getline statement.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` is representation of standard user input and `std::cout` is representation of standard output. If you want the input/output to be read from/written into something different, you have to use that system (e.g. [`std:fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/)).

Your code seems [fine to me](https://ideone.com/GlgNZx).

Comment: Did you use any special command to compile yours? Would compiler version/c++ version make a difference? Mine is not working!!

Comment: What are you using. I compiled it using online compiler (gcc-5.1), but Microsoft CL (distributed with visual studio) works too.

Comment: I used g++ to compile in Linux

Comment: The program will not output anything for fileName. If I i try to output another string "temp" after calling  getline it does not output either. getline is ending my program? Could this be caused by a different part of my program?

Comment: Just try my program alone and check if it works. If it does, you may have some errors in your program.

Comment: @jelly it would help if you posted the *full* program that you are running. Also, try to copy/paste it into an online compiler, like the one that Zereges has used, and see if it works there.